# CSV file upload from buffer to S3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload content taken out of a model in Django as a csv file. I don't want to save the file locally, but keep it in the buffer and upload to s3. Currently, this code does not error as is, and uploads the file properly, however, the file is empty.

```
file_name='some_file.csv'
fields = [list_of_fields]
header = [header_fields]

buff =  io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buff, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(header)
for value in some_queryset:
    row = []
    for field in fields:
        # filling in the row
    writer.writerow(row)

# Upload to s3
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'some_bucket_name'
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
date = date_time.date()
time = date_time.time()
dt = '{year}_{month}_{day}__{hour}_{minute}_{second}'.format(
    day=date.day,
    hour=time.hour,
    minute=time.minute,
    month=date.month,
    second=time.second,
    year=date.year,
)
key = 'some_name_{0}.csv'.format(dt)

client.upload_fileobj(buff, bucket, key)
```

If I take the buffer's content, it is definitely writing it:

```
content = buff.getvalue()
content.encode('utf-8')
print("content: {0}".format(content)) # prints the csv content
```

EDIT: I am doing a similar thing with a zip file, created in a buffer:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(buff, 'w') as archive:
```

Writing to the archive (adding pdf files that I am generating), and once I am done, I execute this: `buff.seek(0)` which seems to be necessary. If I do a similar thing above, it will error out: `Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Got it @halfer now I know. It makes sense :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Okay, disregard my earlier answer, I found the actual problem.

According to the boto3 documentation for the [`upload_fileobj`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj) function, the first parameter (`Fileobj`) needs to implement a read() method that returns bytes:

> Fileobj (a file-like object) -- A file-like object to upload. At a minimum, it must implement the read method, and must return bytes.

The `read()` function on a `_io.StringIO` object returns a string, not bytes. I would suggest swapping the `StringIO` object for a `BytesIO` object, adding in the necessary encoding and decoding.

Here is a minimal working example. It's not the most efficient solution - the basic idea is to copy the contents over to a second `BytesIO` object.

```
import io
import boto3
import csv

buff = io.StringIO()

writer = csv.writer(buff, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(["a", "b", "c"])

buff2 = io.BytesIO(buff.getvalue().encode())

bucket = 'changeme'
key = 'blah.csv'

client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_fileobj(buff2, bucket, key)
```

Comment: Can you show an example please?
I really appreciate your help btw :)

Comment: Almost there! So now the content is not empty, but is random numbers. Is there a way to decode it back somehow? @Thomite
EDIT: Perhaps a line by line encoding rather than the whole file?

Comment: The above example returned sensible data for me - it could just be an encoding mismatch. How are you reading the file back from s3?

Comment: I use encode('utf-8'). (or leave empty is the same)
I have test data with a few cells that should be populated, and the rest should be empty. When I download the csv from S3 (I have a download link) all of the columns are filled with data- two digit integers, and it goes past the designated columns (added new unnamed columns). Is it the byte code? EDIT: The header is good, by the way

Comment: To be clear, after executing my example code, I used the AWS CLI to copy the file to my local directory to see the contents. If you are retrieving the CSV via your browser, it might be assuming a different encoding by default than utf-8. If you follow my approach (directly download the raw file) and the contents are correct, you just need to find the correct encoding that will work with your browser.

Comment: I am using a link that downloads the file directly to my machine, via the browser. Are you saying that the browser is messing up the encoding? I downloaded directly from S3, not via the browser and I get the same numbers all around

Comment: Then the only possible difference between my example and your code is the data you're writing with csv.writerow(). I know the whole point of your question is to avoid the hard drive, but you have tried writing to the hard drive as a debugging solution?

Comment: All is good, +1 for great help debugging :)
Thank you so much @Thomite
(There was some remnant code that encoded to utf-8 when I was trying to do row-by-row, hence the jumbled data)

Comment: It took me a long time to find this, but it solved my problem. thank you!!

Comment: Many many thanks for this, the documentation on boto3 is pathetic.  I can understand if it was only open sourced, but boto3 is critical to AWS and it is the most profitable division at Amazon.  You would think providing basic documentation would be in their best interest. Thanks again!!!!!!

Comment: When should one use `upload_fileobj()` over `put_object()`?

Answer (score 5):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714143/lambda-function-to-write-to-csv-and-upload-to-s3) using the method put_object rather than upload_fileobj would just do the job right with io.STRINGIO object buffer.

So here, to match the initial example:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_fileobj(buff2, bucket, key)
```

would become

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.put_object(Body=buff2, Bucket=bucket, Key=key, ContentType='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling buff.flush() first? It's possible that your entirely-sensible debugging check (calling getvalue()) is creating the illusion that the buff has been written to, but isn't if you don't call it.

Comment: I tried, `buff.flush()` call is between csv-writing to the S3 upload, and the csv file on S3 is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) to redirect output to S3.

Comment: Thank you @khc but I was trying to use what I had already invested in, not use new libraries :)